# How to register event on elements that don't yet exist?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to register a event on elements like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.classname').change(function(){
       alert ('This line is never triggered');
   });
});
```

But the problem is that .classname elements are later loaded into the dom by ajax. So, how do I correctly register an event in this case? Is it possible to do it only once (I mean, not every time the new element appears?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further to the answers suggesting that you use `live()`, it's also possible to use `delegate()`, for example:

```
$('form').delegate('.classname', 'change', function(){
    alert("This will alert when the newly-added element registers a 'change' event.");
});
```

For `delegate` the element to assign the selector (`.classname')` **to**, in this case the `$('form')` must exist in the DOM at the time of assignment.

---

**Edited** to note that the following section (following the next 'edited' until the 'Reference') is **wrong**:

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WAXfc/3/).

Calling `stopPropagation()` on an element between the element selected by the `delegate()` selector and the target to which the event is `delegate()`-d ***does*** somewhat predictably (though I hadn't realised this before) prevent the delegation from occurring.

**Edited** in response to question, in comments, from OP:

> <del>Hey, just noticed, that if any parent's event handler calls stopPropagation, then live event would stop! Is this correct?</del>

<del>Not according to the [jQueryAPI](http://api.jquery.com/) (the entry is linked-to below):</del>

> <del>...events handled by `.delegate()` will always propagate to the element to which they are delegated...</del>

<del>I've not tried/verified this as yet, but it seems that even if an element that sits between the target element (`$('.classname')`) and the `delegate()`-d element (`$('form')`) calls `stopPropagation()` it shouldn't have an adverse effect on the `delegate()`.</del>

Reference:

- [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Comment: Hey, just noticed, that if any parent's event handler calls stopPropagation, then live event would stop! Is this correct?

Comment: I've seen the docs, but have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/WAXfc/1/. The same applies for delegate method, but it safer to use, I think.

Comment: @Dziamid: you're [absolutely right](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WAXfc/3/) (although your linked demo used `live()` rather than `delegate()`, so I updated the demo).

Answer (score 16):

You must use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as live() is deprecated:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( document ).on('change', '.classname', function(){
       alert ('This line is never triggered');
   });
});
```

Comment: live looks really cool. very interesting how the jquery folks were able to make it happen:  "The event bubbles up until it reaches the root of the tree, which is where .live() binds its special handlers by default."  Thanks I did not know about this, I've been doing the binding after every ajax call!

Comment: `live()` is deprecated now. Use `on()`.
See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8191450/1738090

Answer (score 2):

Use `live` which binds the event to all elements now and in the future:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.classname').live('change',function(){
       alert ('This line is never triggered');
   });
});
```

Fore more information, have a look at the [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).